# DateRange picker design flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, daterangepicker

How to design date-Range Picker in flutter
here is my image [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most popular date pickers is [date_picker_timeline](https://pub.dev/packages/date_picker_timeline)

```
Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      DatePicker(
        DateTime.now(),
        initialSelectedDate: DateTime.now(),
        selectionColor: Colors.black,
        selectedTextColor: Colors.white,
        onDateChange: (date) {
          // New date selected
          setState(() {
            _selectedValue = date;
          });
        },
      ),
    ],
)
```

use can also use this one in alert box https://pub.dev/packages/calendar_date_picker2